# La graphie « ambigües » est-elle acceptée ?

Tags: orthographe, standard, diacritiques

Je voulais savoir, le féminin pluriel de *ambigu* est *ambigües*, ou il existe seulement *ambiguës* ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[La réforme de l'orthographe de 1990](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifications_orthographiques_du_fran%C3%A7ais_en_1990#D.C3.A9tail) en fait même la forme officielle.

> 4 Tréma : dans les mots suivants, on place le tréma sur la voyelle qui doit être prononcée : aigüe (et dérivés, comme suraigüe, etc.), ambigüe, exigüe, contigüe, ambigüité, exigüité, contigüité, cigüe. Ces mots appliquent ainsi la règle générale : le tréma indique qu’une lettre (u) doit être prononcée (comme voyelle ou comme semi-voyelle) séparément de la lettre précédente (g).
>   <sub>([Site web de l'Académie Française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/langue/orthographe/graphies.html))</sub>

Cela dit le succès de la réforme étant assez relatif en ce qui concerne les changements de graphies — avec un petit 3% de succès pour *ognon* <sup>[WP](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifications_orthographiques_du_fran%C3%A7ais_en_1990#Diffusion)</sup> — il n'y aucun problème pour utiliser *ambiguë*, sauf avec les fanboys de l'Académie. En fait c'est peut-être même le contraire, certains pourraient trouver *ambigüe* snob s'ils connaissent et désapprouvent la réforme, ou le trouver incorrect sinon.

Le [ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams) suivant semble d'ailleurs confirmer qu'*ambigüe* n'a pas beaucoup de succès
[image: ambigüe vs. ambiguë]

Comment: +1 pour *fanboys de l'Académie* et *ognon*. Comme disent les anglais, "You made my day".

Comment: Il faut également noter que si vous utilisez la nouvelle graphie pour un mot, vous devriez l'utiliser pour le texte en entier. Le mélange des deux graphies au sein d'un même texte n'est pas souhaitable.